# React Native Video HTTP Video Streaming

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native with an Express backend which is handling the video streaming.

I am using this GitHub project as the backend - https://github.com/Abdisalan/blog-code-examples/tree/master/http-video-stream - which basically sends back a chunk of bytes (video data) to the client in a response.

I ran into a problem trying to implement this into my application using react-native-video and expo-av (tried both).

My problem is, when I try to play a video like this it does not work.

```
       <Video
          source={{
           // it's without file extension (backend provides the content type)
            uri: `https://www.apiurl.tld/video/video_id` 
          }}
        />
```

Is there any possible solution to play a video in React Native like this?

Comment: What errors are you getting in either console of the front/back-end?

Comment: No error on backend only on frontend 

Object {
  "error": Object {
    "code": -1,
    "domain": "NSURLErrorDomain",
    "localizedDescription": "unknown error",
    "localizedFailureReason": "",
    "localizedRecoverySuggestion": "",
  },
  "target": 3,
}